# How does \ affect the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, backslash

```
a = "She shouted,\"Hii"
b = "How are you?\""
print (a, b)
```

Also, what does the "" do?

Comment: Your question is about backslash \, not forward slash `/` so I edited the title.

Comment: The back slash character, \, introduces an escape.  In the examples, it precedes a `"`, which is how you can put a `"` character in a string.  If it weren't escaped, it would end the string.

Comment: Use re.escape. Check out this link: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.escape - notice that The '_' character is no longer escaped in version 3.3.